# Jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery

I have mysql table like this:

```
 country   | city_accented |   latitude   |    longitude |
 ---------------------------------------------------------
 australia |    sydney     | -33.8833333  |  151.2166667 |
    USA    |    dallas     |  35.3163889  |  -81.1763889 |
```

I'm using jquery autocomplete to get country names in form text field.
How can I post with this Jquery function all other data from database (latitude, longitude, ...) to my form and use it there like hidden field ?

The Jquery code:

```
function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) {
    // Hide the suggestion box.
    $('#suggestions').hide();
} else {
    $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
        if(data.length >0) {
            $('#suggestions').show();
            $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
        }
    });
}
} // lookup

function fill(thisValue) {
$('#inputString').val(thisValue);
$('#suggestions').hide();
}
```

HTML:

```
<input size="30" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" type="text" />
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
<div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList"></div>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
$queryString = $_POST['queryString'];       
if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city_accented LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("There is an error in database");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$row['city_accented'].'\');">'.$row['city_accented'].','.$row['country'].' </li>';                                        
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than post the html back I would just post the json object back and build the needed html on the client side. So you can get your array back from the mysql call and submit that back:

```
$return_results = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$return_results[] = $row;                      
}

echo json_encode($return_results);
```

Then in the javascript code you can work with that array to do whatever you want with the data. Create the li items. Create hidden fields with data. Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer on this post. Basically you can customise the autocomplete plugin and use the parts of the data you send back for display and usage in separate hidden field!

[Jquery autocomplete - strip tags to enter into input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793220/jquery-autocomplete-strip-tags-to-enter-into-input/8793673#8793673)