# Jquery autocomplete - strip tags to enter into input

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following jquery autocomplete code which works perfectly:

```
$("#autoc1").autocomplete("/autoc2.php?arg=1&category=<? echo $category_id; ?>", {
width: 400,
matchContains: true,
minChars: 3,
selectFirst: false
});
```

I format the data using PHP to show an image in the automplete, for a better more informative UI for the user, the PHP code is:

```
$query = "SELECT $title, imageURL FROM PRprodINFO2 WHERE ((prodcatID = '$cat_id') 
          AND ($title LIKE \"%" . $_GET["q"] . "%\")) group by $title LIMIT 8"; }

$result = mysql_query($query);

$output_items = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    { 

$row[$title] = preg_replace('/[^\w\s].*$/', "", $row[$title]);

$row[$title] = trim($row[$title]);

$output_items[$row['title']] = $row['imageURL'];

} // while

$output_items = array_unique($output_items);

$output = '';

foreach ($output_items as $title => $image) {

$output .= '<img src='.$image.' style=max-width:50px;>'.$title."\n";

}

echo $output;
```

The problem is that the JQuery autocomplete code is pushing the `<img>` tag data into the input as well.

Is there a way to format like this but have only the item title in the input box without the `<img src=/....>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by extending the Autocomplete plugin by overwriting certain core functions, mainly "parse". The internal version of this function simply loops over each line of the returned data and “parses” it into an array of objects, each containing the following attributes:
data – the entire entry
value – the default display value
result – the data to populate the input element on selection

You can overwrite this by passing your own parse function as part of the options object to autocomplete.

you will also need to provide a "formatItem" function that will give you a chance to format the data shown in the autocomplete dropdown!

```
var acOptions = {
    minChars: 3,
    max: 100,
    dataType: 'json', // this parameter is currently unused
    extraParams: {
        format: 'json' // pass the required context to the Zend Controller
    },
        parse: function(data) {
        var parsed = [];
        data = data.users;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            parsed[parsed.length] = {
                data: data[i],
                value: data[i].displayName,
                result: data[i].displayName
            };
        }

        return parsed;
    },
    formatItem: function(item) {
         return item.displayName + ' (' + item.mail + ')';
    }
};
```

Then you can call and also provide a function that can remove the image as required by you  in the .result call as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#user_id')
        .autocomplete('/path/to/ajax/data/source', acOptions)
        .attr('name', 'display_name')
        .after('<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="ac_result">')
        .result(function(e, data) {
            $('#ac_result').val(data.uid); // remove the img here for your text field!
        });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$img = $('img');
$img.replaceWith($img.html());
```

read here [Jquery remove form tag, not content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608547/jquery-remove-form-tag-not-content)